# docker container changes not saving, osx

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, docker, boot2docker

I'm configuring some apps while an image is running then commit the changes

```
  docker commit -m "rabbit queue creation" 3427e02574ea team1/image1:rabbit-shovel
  docker push team1/image1:rabbit-shovel
```

But when I stop and re-start the changes aren't there.

Comment: What changes are missing? `docker commit` does not, for example, take a snapshot of RAM. `commit` only keeps the changes that are on disk.

Comment: @Andy I created a queue, an exchange and bound them in rabbitmq. Then in elasticsearch I created an index.

Comment: you have to do the snapshot while the container is running. If you exit from the container then all the changes will be lost

Comment: @fabrizioM Yes, I do the commit while it's running. Is there a refresh or reload option I'm missing. I ensure I use the correct tag.

Comment: how does this apply to data containers.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you run `docker run' it starts a new container, i.e. generates a new container id.

Do a `docker ps -a` to see all containers and make sure your container id is for the correct container instance you want to `docker commit` as a new image.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

To make your changes persistent, you need to save it using : docker commit old newcontainername